# How to insert and fill the rows with calculated value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with missing theta steps as below,

```
index  name theta r
1      wind 0     10
2      wind 30    17
3      wind 60    19
4      wind 90    14
5      wind 120   17
6      wind 210   18
7      wind 240   17
8      wind 270   11
9      wind 300   13
```

I need to add the missing theta with values,

```
index  name theta r
1      wind 0     10
2      wind 30    17
3      wind 60    19
4      wind 90    14
5      wind 120   17
6      wind 150   null
7      wind 180   null
8      wind 210   18
9      wind 240   17
10     wind 270   11
11     wind 300   13
12     wind 330   null
```

And then fill the null values with linear interpolation. For simplicity here we can consider average of previous and next available value,

```
index  name theta r
1      wind 0     10
2      wind 30    17
3      wind 60    19
4      wind 90    14
5      wind 120   17
6      wind 150   17.5 #(17 + 18)/2
7      wind 180   17.5 #(17 + 18)/2
8      wind 210   18
9      wind 240   17
10     wind 270   11
11     wind 300   13
12     wind 330   11.5 #(13 + 10)/2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
out = (
 df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30))
   .interpolate().ffill().reset_index()[df.columns]
)
```

Output:

```
    name  theta          r
0   wind      0  10.000000
1   wind     30  17.000000
2   wind     60  19.000000
3   wind     90  14.000000
4   wind    120  17.000000
5   wind    150  17.333333
6   wind    180  17.666667
7   wind    210  18.000000
8   wind    240  17.000000
9   wind    270  11.000000
10  wind    300  13.000000
11  wind    330  13.000000
```

Performing a circular interpolation, you can only fill the inner values with `limit_area='inside'`, then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the mean of the first and last valid rows:

```
out = (
 df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30))
   .interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.fillna(d.dropna().iloc[[0, -1]].select_dtypes('number').mean()))
   .ffill().reset_index()[df.columns]
)
```

Output:

```
    name  theta          r
0   wind      0  10.000000
1   wind     30  17.000000
2   wind     60  19.000000
3   wind     90  14.000000
4   wind    120  17.000000
5   wind    150  17.333333
6   wind    180  17.666667
7   wind    210  18.000000
8   wind    240  17.000000
9   wind    270  11.000000
10  wind    300  13.000000
11  wind    330  11.500000
```

If you really want the same values for multiple intermediates, another option could be to compute yourself the mean (with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)):

```
tmp = df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30))
tmp2 = tmp.ffill()

out = ((tmp2+tmp.bfill().fillna(df.iloc[0]))
       .select_dtypes('number').div(2)
       .combine_first(tmp2).reset_index()[df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
    name  theta     r
0   wind      0  10.0
1   wind     30  17.0
2   wind     60  19.0
3   wind     90  14.0
4   wind    120  17.0
5   wind    150  17.5  # same values
6   wind    180  17.5  #
7   wind    210  18.0
8   wind    240  17.0
9   wind    270  11.0
10  wind    300  13.0
11  wind    330  11.5
```

*NB. these approaches should work with any number of numeric columns (not just `'r'`).*

#### working with groups

One simple approach is to use a function and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
def interp(df):
    return  (
 df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30))
   .interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.fillna(d.dropna().iloc[[0, -1]].select_dtypes('number').mean()))
   .ffill().reset_index()[df.columns]
)

out = df.groupby('name', group_keys=False).apply(interp)
```

Or, first [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your data:

```
out = (
 df.pivot(index='theta', columns='name')
   .reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30))
   .interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.fillna(d.dropna().iloc[[0, -1]].select_dtypes('number').mean()))
   .ffill().stack().reset_index()[df.columns]
)
```

Example output (`#` shows the initially missing values):

```
    name  theta           r
0   turb      0  100.000000
1   turb     30  170.000000
2   turb     60  190.000000
3   turb     90  140.000000
4   turb    120  170.000000
5   turb    150  173.333333  #
6   turb    180  176.666667  #
7   turb    210  180.000000
8   turb    240  170.000000
9   turb    270  110.000000
10  turb    300  130.000000
11  turb    330  115.000000  #
0   wind      0   10.000000
1   wind     30   17.000000
2   wind     60   19.000000
3   wind     90   14.000000
4   wind    120   17.000000  #
5   wind    150   17.333333  #
6   wind    180   17.666667
7   wind    210   18.000000
8   wind    240   17.000000
9   wind    270   11.000000
10  wind    300   13.000000
11  wind    330   11.500000  #
```

With `bfill`/`ffill`:

```
tmp = (df.set_index(['name', 'theta'])
         .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['name'].unique(), range(0, 330+1, 30)],
                                             names=['name', 'theta']
                                            ))
      )
tmp2 = tmp.groupby(level='name').ffill()

out = ((tmp2+tmp.groupby(level='name').bfill().fillna(df.iloc[0]))
       .select_dtypes('number').div(2)
       .combine_first(tmp2).reset_index()[df.columns]
      )
```

Comment: Thaks @mozway. One more question. I have turb along with wind in the same df. So, I modified yours as below,
`
df.set_index(['name','theta']).reindex(range(0, 330+1, 30), level=1)
`
Although pandas is not throwing any error but the new rows are not inserted. Is it possible to support on this?

Note: Sorry, I thought this detail will be irrelevant while asking question

Comment: No, the index should only contain "theta" for reindexing. If you have several groups either unstack/pivot your names as columns or use a groupby interpolation. I'll show you an example

Answer (score 2):

If there is same value in `name` column you can use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `range` with divide forwar and back filling values with replace last missing values in `s2` by first value of `s1`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 360, 30))

s1 = df1['r'].ffill()  
s2 = df1['r'].bfill().fillna(s1.iat[0])  

df = s1.add(s2).div(2).reset_index().assign(name = 'wind')[df.columns]
print (df)
    name  theta     r
0   wind      0  10.0
1   wind     30  17.0
2   wind     60  19.0
3   wind     90  14.0
4   wind    120  17.0
5   wind    150  17.5
6   wind    180  17.5
7   wind    210  18.0
8   wind    240  17.0
9   wind    270  11.0
10  wind    300  13.0
11  wind    330  11.5
```

Solution with interpolation with [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) and helper row by backfilled values of `r`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 360, 30))

df = (pd.concat([df1, df1[['r']].bfill().iloc[[0]]])
        .interpolate().reset_index().iloc[:-1].assign(name='wind')[df.columns])

print (df)
    name  theta          r
0   wind      0  10.000000
1   wind     30  17.000000
2   wind     60  19.000000
3   wind     90  14.000000
4   wind    120  17.000000
5   wind    150  17.333333
6   wind    180  17.666667
7   wind    210  18.000000
8   wind    240  17.000000
9   wind    270  11.000000
10  wind    300  13.000000
11  wind    330  11.500000
```

If possible missing first row:

```
print (df)
   name  theta   r
2  wind     30  17
3  wind     60  19
4  wind     90  14
5  wind    120  17
6  wind    210  18
7  wind    240  17
8  wind    270  11
9  wind    300  13


df1 = df.set_index('theta').reindex(range(0, 360, 30))

df = (pd.concat([df1[['r']].ffill().iloc[[-1]], 
                 df1, 
                 df1[['r']].bfill().iloc[[0]]])
        .interpolate().reset_index().iloc[1:-1].assign(name='wind')[df.columns])

print (df)
    name  theta          r
1   wind      0  15.000000
2   wind     30  17.000000
3   wind     60  19.000000
4   wind     90  14.000000
5   wind    120  17.000000
6   wind    150  17.333333
7   wind    180  17.666667
8   wind    210  18.000000
9   wind    240  17.000000
10  wind    270  11.000000
11  wind    300  13.000000
12  wind    330  15.000000
```

Comment: Can you please clarify me, how to copy the tabular contents from question to a dataframe? My present approach: I am copying the contents to a python string, split(), then to a numpy array, reshape, into a dataframe and finally convert datatypes.